# about the probability of the first playlist

Tags: probability

One boy created two sets of music. First in 2010. Last one - 2017. In his first playlist distribution over genres was following:

- 40% - rock
- 20% - pop
- 20% - jazz
- 10% - country music
- 10% - classical.

In his next play list distribution changed:

- 24% - electronic music
- 20% - classical
- 16% - country music
- 14% - jazz
- 13% - pop
- 13% - rock.

Than, boy played one after another **one track** from each playlist.
In first case it was jazz, and in the second - classical.

**Question**: Find the probability that first playlist was created in 2010.
Please, I'm stuck with this problem and have no guess where to start, as have low skills in probability theory. Thanks!

Comment: It appears you are "passing through" an assigned exercise without having given much thought to its meaning.  The exercise was doubtless intended to reinforce the understanding of material covered just before the appearance of this problem.  In any case the hypotheses here allow for two alternatives, i.e. the tracks either begin with a random choice from the 2010 playlist (followed by a second track from the 2017 playlist) or vice versa.  Have you studied conditional probability and Bayes formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to do here is as follows.

1. Work out the probability that he chooses the 2010 playlist first, chooses jazz from the 2010 playlist, and chooses classical from the 2017 playlist. Call this $p$.
2. Work out the probability that he chooses the 2017 playlist first, chooses jazz from the 2017 playlist, and chooses classical from the 2010 playlist. Call this $q$.
3. The answer is $\frac p{p+q}$. This is because you will hear jazz followed by classical $p+q$ of the time, and $p$ of that will be case 1, with $q$ of it being case 2.

Comment: is this true, that I will get 0,625 ?

Comment: That's not what I get. What are your values for $p$ and $q$?

Comment: hm, sorry, i've recalculated,suppose **p** = 0.04 and **q** = 0.014 ?

Comment: That looks better. I had $p=0.02$ and $q=0.007$ because I factored in the $50\%$ chance of picking 2010 first or 2017 first, but your values give the same answer.